# Custom field post help results in "Unable to load help file."

Tags: custom-fields

The blue help bubble has stopped working on all my custom data fields. The error is shown in the snippet below, "Unable to load help file." Help for non-custom fields continues to work as usual. Clearing caches and resetting paths didn't help. At a loss for what else to do, I restarted the server to no avail. The CiviCRM log file records the exception in the text below the snippet.

CiviCRM 5.61.1, Drupal 7.97, MySQL 5.7.42, PHP 7.4.33

[image: Custom field help error]

```
May 18 20:36:16  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(471): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/civiprod/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "inline")
#4 /home/civiprod/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#5 {main}


May 18 20:42:48  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Invalid {htxt} tag. Wrapped 0 opening-tags and 1 closing-tags."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => RuntimeException {#1347
    #message: "Invalid {htxt} tag. Wrapped 0 opening-tags and 1 closing-tags."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/prefilter.htxtFilter.php"
    #line: 32
    trace: {
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/prefilter.htxtFilter.php:32 {
        smarty_prefilter_htxtFilter($tpl_source, &$smarty)
        › if ($htxts !== $_htxts) {
        ›   throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Invalid {htxt} tag. Wrapped %d opening-tags and %d closing-tags.', $htxts, $_htxts));
        › }
      }
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php:248 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php:1499 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php:1432 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php:1271 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php:192 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Inline/Help.php:36 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/AJAX.php:59 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:285 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:471 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
      /home/civiprod/public_html/index.php:21 { …}
    }
  }
]


May 18 20:42:48  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 /home/civiprod/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(471): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/civiprod/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "inline")
#4 /home/civiprod/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#5 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a regression to me, I can confirm it works on 5.58.1 but not dmaster, so not on the most recent version. I'd recommend posting an issue on Gitlab: https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Comment: Thanks Lars, issue created - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4303